# Generate different tables based on some id from the final result table in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net, database, stored-procedures

I have a final table from the SQL result as for example

```
id            student
------------------------
 1            john
 1            mark
 2            robert
 2            kumar
```

and I want tables from the above table dynamically based on ids of final result from a single procedure as

first table

```
id          student
-------------------
 1          john
 1          mark
```

and second table result

```
id         student
-----------------------
 2         robert
 2         kumar
```

How to achive it? Thank you in advance

Comment: Using `Where id =1` and `Where id=2` ??

Comment: no i want dynamically in single procedure

Comment: What you mean by saying: "generate different tables"?

Comment: sorry its dynamic tables based on final tables

Comment: Dynamic tables? You probably mean you want 2 or more result sets... Am i right?

Comment: yeah you are up to the point

Comment: So, fetch the distinct id's from table. Then use cursor to be able to loop through the collection of records. Inside a loop call query `SELECT <FieldList> FROM TableName WHERE ID = @ValueFetchedByTheCursor` as Coder of Code mentioned.

Comment: from this i think the loop will select for the last distinct id and i will get the last dynamic tables only what about the rest.

Comment: @dazzlingkumar you can achieve this genreating dynamic queries not looping/cursor. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to create dynamic queries based on ids and execute the query.

```
create table student(id int, name varchar(30))
insert into student values
(1, 'john'),
(2, 'mark')

declare @qry varchar(max) = ''

select @qry=@qry+ 'select * from student where id = ' +   cast (id  as varchar) + '; ' from
(
select distinct id  from student
) w

exec (@qry)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Quite different method than mine (in comment to the question), but looks perfectly ;)

Comment: @MaciejLos but i think from your method(in comment to the question), we can get only the last one,  really selva is a genius ;)

Comment: @dazzlingkumar, The base idea is the same. As i mentioned in my comment to the question, you need to loop through the collection of id's to be able to call different queries (to get different result sets).

Comment: @dazzlingkumar you can tweak and optimize this (replacing distinct by passing the ids from app, etc).